# What is the * 'class' in swing user interface?

Tags: java, swing

I have seen this in my lecture's code examples but never in the main lecture notes. I haven't been able to find any information on it online either. What is the * 'class' (if it is even a class) in:

```
package graphicsExample;
import java.swing.*;
    ...
```

In other what's, what does importing this do?

Comment: its a wildcard..imports every classes inside of swing package

Comment: There might be a [manual to read.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to find this. This is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's importing all classes from a single package, i.e.

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

imports the classes/interfaces/enums/exceptions the classes listed here (not including nested classes/interfaces/ect.): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html